# Change message "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity PasswordValidator and was hoping with some assistance with changing this default message so that it is more clear.

How can I change this message and include special character for example?

```
 manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 10,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a folder for **IdentityExtensions**, Add a class **CustomPasswordValidator** In that class you need to referance **IIdentityValidator** below is how i overide password Validation.

Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace YourNameSpace.IdentityExtensions
{
    public class CustomPasswordValidator : IIdentityValidator<string>
    {
        public int RequiredLength { get; set; }
        public CustomPasswordValidator(int length)
        {
            RequiredLength = length;
        }

        public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) || item.Length < RequiredLength)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(String.Format("Password should be of length {0}", RequiredLength)));
            }

            string pattern = @"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*0-9]{10,}$";

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed("Password should have one numeral and one special character"));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem glad i could help